# Generating tables with headers from code block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, org-table

I would like to generate tables that have headers from code blocks. Something like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results value table :table-header | First | Second |
  (identity '((a b) (c d)))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| First | Second |
|-------+--------|
| a     | b      |
| c     | d      |
```

Unfortunately something like `:table-header | First | Second |` does not exist.  Or rather I am hoping that I am overlooking something. (Here I am using `(identity ...)` as a placeholder for code which actually calculates a value.)

This workaround doesn't quite do it for me:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results value table
  (cons (list "First" "Second")
        (identity '((a b) (c d))))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| First | Second |
| a     | b      |
| c     | d      |
```

I have to modify the content of the code block and the resulting header is not actually a header row, its a row like any other.

Related to this (but not 100% the same, above I would like to avoid having to put table setup instructions *inside* the code block, below that is required), is there a special element that causes the insertion of a separator? Something like:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results value table
  (nconc (identity '((a b) (c d)))  ; calculated value A
         (list 'linebreak)          ; explicitly inserted linebreak
         (identity '((A B) (C D)))) ; calculated value B
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| a | b |
| c | d |
|---+---|
| A | B |
| B | D |
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use `hline` instead of `linebreak`.
The following works:

```
* test
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results value table
  '(("First" "Second")
    hline
    (a b) (c d))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| First | Second |
|-------+--------|
| a     | b      |
| c     | d      |
```

Comment: After having played with `:colnames` as suggested in the other answer, it looks like I'll have to open feature request for `#+BEGIN_SRC ... :colnames yes` as well as `:colnames "| First | Second |"`. Until then I will go with this approach.

Comment: Just a note in case anyone finds this a helpful addition: If you're not using `quote`d values for everything (e.g. maybe you're using a `:var` header and `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. are actually derived variables which you use `list` on), just quote the `'hline` symbol itself.

Answer (score 3):

After adding the header row:

1. **Assign `#+NAME:` to code block.**

   ```
   #+NAME: needs-a-table-header
   #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results value table 
     (cons (list "First" "Second")
           (identity '((a b) (c d))))
   #+END_SRC
   ```
2. **Add `#+CALL:` statement with `:colnames yes` header**

   ```
   #+CALL: needs-a-table-header() :colnames yes
   ```
3. **Run `#+CALL:` statement using <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd>.**

   ```
   #+RESULTS:
   | First | Second |
   |-------+--------|
   | a     | b      |
   | c     | d      |
   ```

Hope that helped!

---

> Code Tested using
>
> GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.14.13)
>   org-version: 8.3.2

Comment: Thanks. To avoid having two tables I prefixed both the code block and the call with `#+NAME: same-name`. Since I still have to cons the header row when using this approach, I'll go with the solution in the other answer.

Comment: @tarsius Thanks for update! BTW **thanks for asking this question!** I know of several different ways to add table headers which you might find helpful. I'll look through my notes an post another answer.