# How to return an org mode table with headings and hline from Ruby

Tags: org-babel, org-table, ruby

I have the same question as [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20710/10291) except that I don't see how to do so other than in elisp.  I am using Ruby, but I suppose the question applies to other languages as well.  If I return an array of arrays as the value result of some code, I want to have it formatted as a table headed with the column names.

Here is the solution to what I want in elisp:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results value table
  '(("First" "Second")
    hline
    (a b) (c d))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| First | Second |
|-------+--------|
| a     | b      |
| c     | d      |
```

But I've tried variants of this in Ruby with no luck.  For example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ruby :results value table
    [ [ 'First', 'Second'],
      :hline,
      [ :a, :b ],
      [ :c, :d ]
    ]
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| (First Second) | :hline | (:a :b) | (:c :d) |
```

Which is not what I want.  So, what is the incantation to use here?

Comment: You could try the colnames header argument, for example `:colnames '("First" "Second")`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a way to do it from within the code.

Answer (score 5):

For others who may want to know the answer, I finally figured it out.  In the case of ruby, you should insert a nil where you want the hline to appear.  Org represents a table as an array of arrays.

Here is what I used to discover the right incantation for ruby:

```
#+NAME: test
|  Ref | Value |
|------+-------|
| 0001 | blue  |
| 0002 | red   |

#+HEADER: :colnames no
#+HEADER: :hlines yes
#+HEADER: :results value raw
#+BEGIN_SRC ruby :var tab=test
 tab
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
[["Ref", "Value"], nil, [1, "blue"], [2, "red"]]
```

So to generate a table with column headers and an hline, just produce an array of arrays with the first sub-array an array of headings and the second element a nil instead of a sub-array.

Just use a SRC block for your favorite language to discover how it represents headings.

Comment: The same idea works for Python: supplying a `None` as a row will produce a hline.